# How to generate constant typescript enums from protobuf?

Tags: grpc, proto, grpc-node, protobuf.js

I have this protobuf code

```
enum Language {
 en = 0;
 jp = 1;
 ar = 2;
}
```

When it's generated to typescript the values become `Lanuage.en = 0`, `Language.jp = 1` ...

What I want is `Language.en = "ENGLISH"`, `Language.ar = "ARABIC"`

How to achieve this?